# Images loading in blade template file gives 404 on windows environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi I am new to Laravel and trying to migrate a wordpress website to Laravel framework. I installed Laravel using composer on my windows machine and I am able to view the welcome page at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' after I start the server using command 'artisan server serve'. However I am trying to load an image in one of the blad.php files using the following code 
""
but on the front end I get 404 not found with the URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/logo.jpg'.
The logo.jpg file is inside images folder under public folder of the application.
Any help in resolving this issue will be highly appreciated.
I am not using homestead or any other environment but simple Laravel 5.x and Php 7.X.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's an issue with permission for `public/` directory. Make sure the permissions are correct before loading that image.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I know in Linux/Unix we set permissions using commands but how do you set them windows environment because I have never set any permissions after the fresh installation of Laravel?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373

Comment: I tried changing file permissions by deselecting checkbox of Read only for the file and folder both and still I can't see any image present inside the images folder under public. I am using the following way to display images. <img src="{!!URL::asset{'images/logo.jpg'}" alt="Image not found" >

Comment: try `<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.jpg) }}" alt="Image not found" >`